# waiting for multiple Python processes to finish in Windows 7 CMD

Tags: python, windows, cmd, parallel-processing

I am trying to run multiple Python scripts in parallel in Windows 7 (and 10). I am running them all from another Python script, which performs more functions on the files the scripts are editing.  I want the external script to wait until the other scripts are done running. I have tried `start /w`, but that made each script wait before closing the console window.

Essentially what I want to do is for Python to wait until the 3 processes are done. The last script is just a `print("done")`, and is meaningless for all I care. This is important for me to solve with 3 processes because I need to do the same thing with 30. (On a server, there are enough available threads.)

This is the CMD command I am trying to run.

```
os.system("start python node1.py & start python node2.py & start python node3.py && start /w printstatement.py")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Could you be little more clear. Finding difficult to comprehend. So far, you're trying to run three programs in parallel from a master script and the master script has something what the programs edit. Am I correct?

Comment: you are. the master script runs 3 different tasks using the above example. it needs to wait for them all to finish before carrying on with other tasks. since i don't want for the program to sleep for an estimated period of time i need it to wait for all the processes to finish.

Comment: Mm... Is your last script "printstatement.py" dependent on the outcome of the previous three?

And your master script has something else to do besides running the three scripts in parallel?

Have you tried "multiprocessing" for parallellizing the whole process?

Comment: i did try that. there is a problem because of multiple different I\O parameters for each script.

Comment: @eryksun can you provide an example of `subprocess.Popen` can replace `os.system` with multiple scripts to run?

Comment: @eryksun that solved my problem perfectly. Thank you. if you would post this as an answer i would like to accept it for others to learn from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`. You'll get 3 `Popen` instances that you can wait on. For example:

```
import subprocess

procs = [subprocess.Popen(['python', 'node{}.py'.format(n)]) 
            for n in range(1, 4)]

retcodes = [p.wait() for p in procs]
```

If you want separate console windows, like how CMD's `start` command works, then add the option `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to the `Popen` call (Windows only). If you instead want separate consoles that don't create windows, use `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (0x08000000). In this case they still have console standard I/O; it's just not rendered to a window.

Comment: Again this worked perfectly. The windows were actualy really annoying so getting rid of them was a blessing

Comment: Really nice way of doing this!!

Comment: Nice idiomatic hack

Answer (score 0):

Solution using asyncio:

```
import asyncio

commands = [
    'python node1.py',
    'python node2.py',
]

async def run_command(command):
    task = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*command.split())
    await task.wait()

combined_task = asyncio.gather(*(run_command(command) for command in commands))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(combined_task)
```